# Ranking estimation with partial data

Tags: estimation, ranking, posterior

Consider a problem where we ask a number of people to select and rank their top **three** choices out of a number of options. The set of options is the same for everyone, and they all have to rank their top three choices.

How can I go about the estimating the ranking of the options given data collected? How can I model the problem?

For example, say that we get the following data (only showing the first four options, and the rankings whenever someone included them in the ranking):

```
Option A: 1
Option B: 1,3,1,2,1
Option C: 3,3
Option D: 2,2,2
```

Where the way to read the above is:

- First row: Only one person chose `A` as their top choice
- Second row: Three people chose `B` as their top choice, one person chose it as their second best choice and one more person chose it as its third choice.

A trivial, but unhelpful answer would be to average the ranking for each option. That would be:

```
Option A: 1
Option B: (1+3+1+2+1)/5 = 1.6
Option C: (3+3)/2 = 3
Option D: (2+2+2)/3 = 2
```

The above averaging is unhelpful because it would not consider the number of people that chose a given option, and given the way the experiment is designed, the more often a given option is chosen in the top 3 list, the higher the ranking should be.

How can I go about modeling this problem?

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to assume the average of the ranked choices.

For example, suppose you have six options, ABCDEF.  Suppose Joe picks A, D, and C as their first, second and third choice.

Then if there was a full ranking, B, E and F would occupy positions 4,5,6 in some unknown order.  So why not pretend they all have the average of those ranks, i.e. 5, for Joe?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following three *broad approaches* might be helpful for this scenario. If I understand the scenario correctly, I would call this task a *statistical modeling of surveys with partial data*. The three **approaches** that I would consider are (please correct me, if I wrong - I'm *learning* statistics):

- **Cross-validation techniques** (for a comprehensive description, see [this paper](http://mathematiques.univ-lille1.fr/digitalAssets/5/5684_ArlotCelisse-69-VII.pdf));
- **Survey weighting** (for details, please see [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/146146448X) and [this research paper](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/STS226.pdf));
- **Missing values imputation** (that is to *re-formulate the problem* as a *missing data* problem).